# Piping adb output to less behaves unpredictably

Tags: less, stdin, adb

Using `less` to view the output of some `adb` commands often does not work as expected.

For example hitting the spacebar to advance to the next screen often does nothing, but hitting the spacebar a second time will advance. (But this is inconsistent.)

Another quirk is that searching for a regular expression will return "Pattern not found" even though the pattern does actually exist.

To reproduce:

```bsh
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler | less
```

Actual behavior:

- Hitting spacebar does not always advance to the next screen

Expected behavior:

- Hitting spacebar reliably advances to the next screen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `adb shell` reads from stdin (this does not appear to be documented), and this conflicts with less's efforts to also read from stdin.

A few ways to fix this:

```bsh
# Provide the -n ("don't read from shell") switch
adb shell -n dumpsys jobscheduler | less

# Read from /dev/null
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler </dev/null | less

# Replace "shell" with the (undocumented) exec-out command, which does not redirect stdin
adb exec-out dumpsys jobscheduler | less

# Run adb via process substitution
less <(adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler)
```